# Using Threads for Multiple marker detection in OpenCV

Tags: visual-c++, opencv, augmented-reality

I'm working on an Augmented Reality project in which I have to do "multiple marker detection + identification" using OpenCV. I'm on Windows, Visual C++ 2008. I have done up to the Single threaded part.

I was wondering if there are any *Threading mechanisms* already available in OpenCV for doing a similar task. Else what are other methods I can consider?

I'm also hoping to use the rotation and translation matrices generated for each marker (using OpenCV) when overlaying 3D models. Is there a better way to organize/keep these data?

**EDIT:**

This is for an academic project where efficiency and other matters are not that important. It's perfectly fine as long as it's a working solution.

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are trying to accomplish. Can you ellaborate further? What are alghorithms are you using? At least try to do a skatch of your overall approach to detect/identify your markers. 
Do you want to use multiple threads to detect multiple markers or run trought the input image in parallell to detect and merge the results?

Comment: It is very similar to ARToolkit library. But I'm doing accomplishing the same using OpenCV+OpenGL+Qt. Requirements: 1) when the number of markers increase the detection time should be minimized than in a single threaded application. 3) 3D content must be drawn as soon as marker detection+identification (basic image processing techniques used) is finished.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is using the Boost library in combination with a concurrent queue. Here you can find a [concurrent queue](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/implementing-a-thread-safe-queue-using-condition-variables.html) that I made working together with boost threading and OpenCV.

To use the concurrent queue with OpenCV you could thread it something like this:

```
    boost::thread_group frame_workers;   
    concurrent_queue<IplImage* > frame_queue(&frame_workers);

    boost::thread * frame_thread = new boost::thread(frame_grabber, &frame_queue);
    boost::thread * marker_thread = new boost::thread(marker_handler, &frame_queue);

    frame_workers.add_thread(frame_thread);
    frame_workers.add_thread(marker_thread);
```

In the frame_grabber function you can grab frames and push them into the frame_queue. When doing this, the marker_thread is notified that there is a frame waiting in the queue (with wait_and_pop). A short example for the grabbing part can be something like this:

```
 void frame_grabber(concurrent_queue<IplImage* > * frame_queue) {
     frame = cvQueryFrame(input_video);
     frame_copy = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), 8, 3);
     cvCopy(frame, frame_copy);
     frame_queue->push(frame);
 }
```